# Can docker be used to run a web site container that first downloads latest version prior to running web server?

Tags: docker

I've been experimenting with docker recently but can't get my head around what I think is a fairly important/useful requirement:

The ability to download a NEW copy of a web site for running, when a container is run. NOT at build time, but at run time.

I have seen countless examples of Dockerfiles where java, tomcat, a copy of a WAR is installed and added to an image during build time, but none where that WAR is downloaded fresh each time "docker run -d me/myimage" is executed on the command line.

I think it might involve adding a CMD statement at the end of the Dockerfile but I wonder if people out there more experienced than me with docker have some advice? Perhaps I shouldn't even be attempting this and should re-build my images each time my web app has a new release? But that would mean I would have to distribute my new image via a private dockerhub or something right? I am not willing to stick my source in a public github repo and have the Dockerfile pull it and build it during an image build.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this, but it's more normal to build a container instance for each version of your software.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark O'Connor said in his comment, it's certainly possible.  A Docker container is just a process tree running on your Linux host, and with a few exceptions (generally involving privileged access to the kernel) can do anything you can do *outside* of a container.

So sure, you could put together an image that, when run, would download the most recent of an application and run it.

The reason this is considered a bad idea is that it suddenly becomes difficult if you want to run an *older* version of the application (or more generally a *specific* version).  What if you redeploy your container and end up with a new version of the application that requires manual database schema upgrades before it will operate?  Now instead of an application you have a brick.

Similarly, what if the newest version of the application is simply buggy?  If you were performing the download and install at *build* time, you would simply deploy an image with an older version of the application.

Performing the application and download at *run* time makes the container unpredictable and less manageable.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - so what would be a sane approach to creating a new image per release (from a deployment perspective - I dont want to end up building a new image locally and then having to save/export it and upload it to my cloud server - the image is about 1.9Gb at the moment - I suppose I start with a my own base image that doesn't contain WAR and "pull" that on server, and the create new image that includes WAR and CMD to   run it, all on the remote server?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best answer is.  With a large image like that, maybe you'll decide that the most manageable solution is what you started with -- performing the install at runtime.  Maybe you could instrument your image such that you can pass an application version as an environment variable.  Maybe it's also possible to reduce the image size to where it's somewhat more manageable.  There isn't really a single best solution.